# Create Topic on Telegram groups

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

Using python there's a way to create Topics on Telegram? I'm trying to find something about this but I don't find anything, probably I'm just not looking on the right place, I was doing something like this but obviously not longer works:

```
import telegram
import asyncio

async def create_topic():
    bot = telegram.Bot(token="XXXX000000XXXXX")

    chat = await bot.get_chat(chat_id=-0000000)

    topic_name = "My New Topic"

    # Create the topic
    result = chat.create_topic(topic_name)

    # Check if the topic was created successfully
    if result:
        print("Topic created successfully!")
    else:
        print("Failed to create topic.")
    
asyncio.run(create_topic())
```

Anybody have any Idea of how make topics? or it's not longer possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the method [`Chat.create_forum_topic`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.chat.html#telegram.Chat.create_forum_topic). The full list of available API methods related to forums topics can be found in the [official Telegram Bot API docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getforumtopiciconstickers) and you can find the corresponding PTB counterparts in the docs of the [`Bot`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.bot.html) class.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay I got some medical issues, there's a way to get all the id's of the topics from a group? also the titles? I'm trying to make some terminal window to control one of my groups, so I can add, remove and send files to specific topics at any moment

Comment: No, you'd have to keep track of that.